# How to setup a sql trigger in MySQL 5.5 that only checks the inserted row

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in MySQL 5.5 where the CHECK constraint is not available. My goal is to not allow a row to be inserted where a customerId is less than or equal to zero.

My problem is that the line:

```
ON PlatformAccount FOR EACH ROW
```

correct me if I'm wrong, will look through all rows in the table. This a performance hit that I do not want.

How do setup this trigger to only validate that the inserted row follows this constraint?

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER platform_account_trigger
BEFORE INSERT
   ON PlatformAccount FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.customerId <= 0 THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '99999'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'You cannot insert a row without a customerId greater than zero';
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Have a little look at the documentation, which explicitly states that it only affects the modified rows and not the whole table: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to be corrected. This part:

`FOR EACH ROW`

indicates that the trigger will be fired once for each affected row; only the row(s) being inserted or updated.

This does not mean the trigger is fired for every row that exists in the table. (We could create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, and then run an UPDATE statement that  changes *every* row in the table; then the trigger would be fired for *every* row in the table; but only because the trigger gets fired for each row being updated.

---

Some databases other than MySQL (e.g. Oracle) support statement level triggers, that get fired once for each statement execution, rather than being fired for each affected row. Those statement level triggers are defined by leaving off the `FOR EACH ROW` bit.  MySQL doesn't currently support statement level triggers; triggers in MySQL are row level triggers, get fired for each affected row.